# Keep chart/graph style

Tags: charts, styles, shapes

Is it possible to keep the chart style (shape styles) from a xlsx file when I read and write it? With my code below the style is lost .

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';



use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx AS WXlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Chart;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;


echo "Opening file...<br>";
$spreadsheet = new Xlsx();
$spreadsheet->setIncludeCharts(true);
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheet->load("test.xlsx");

echo "Saving file...<br>";
$fileName = "testKeepChart.xlsx";
$writer = new WXlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->save($fileName);

echo "File saved as $fileName.\n";
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

When using excel like templates (from existing files), charts won't load. Issue [reported here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/382), though probably won't be fixed.